# Raspberry Pi 3 freezes after GUI Python program is minimised/closed

Tags: python, pi-3, raspbian-jessie, gui

I am using the Raspberry Pi 3 alongwith its 7-inch screen. I have developed a software that shows real-time temperature on the screen alongwith some other functions.

The software runs fine without any glitch for an infinite amount of time(tested it for 2-3 days at a stretch). But once I minimise or close my software, nothing else seems to work. Most importantly, the file explorer does not open. It hangs! No other file can be opened (even if it is on the desktop). And if I reopen the software, it again runs fine.

The software is GUI based and has been developed in Python. The OS I am using is Raspbian-Jessie.

Comment: Test your code by developing a [Hello World](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22Hello,_World!%22_program) application in the same style. If it runs as it should the problem's in your code, and you should redefine your question for [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/). If it doesn't then there's some kind of undesirable interaction going on between one or more of your Python modules and Jessie, and you should check for bug reports on the developer's support pages.

Comment: Hi. It has been solved. It was an error due to the usage of the matchbox keyboard. Which ysed to generate a process named pcmanfm whose CPU usage used to be 100%. Which wouldn't stop even if the keyboard was closed. Hence, it used to interrupt the normal functioning of the Pi. As a solution, I used python to find its PID and then kill it using sudo kill -9 PID

Comment: Really great to hear you found a solution! If you write it up as an answer there's a decent chance you'll score some points for it, and it may help other users in the future.